# Javascript Web Audio API error: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'AudioParam': The provided float value is non-finite

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have no idea what this means. I have a feeling something in the Web Audio API has changed recently, and the browsers have implemented the change as my application was working fine with no errors the last time I checked it about 2 weeks ago. I have changed nothing in my code recently since the last time it was working.

The error I am getting is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'value' property on
>   'AudioParam': The provided float value is non-finite.

The line where the error occurs is this line:

```
gainNode.gain.value = volume;
```

The application can be viewed here: 
http://aceroinc.ca/harmanKardon/

When the power button is hit, the app should turn on and a radio station should begin streaming. **(In chrome only... the .aac format will not work in Firefox and I am aware of that)**

I initialize the web audio api after the DOM loads...

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
context = new AudioContext();
source =context.createMediaElementSource(document.getElementById('audio'));
gainNode = context.createGain();
var gainDefault = gainNode.gain.defaultValue;
```

Then down inside the powerOn function I have:

```
gainNode.gain.value = currVolume;
```

which is causing the error.

When I check it in safari on my iphone the application works. So this seems to be a chrome issue.

On my desktop computer I have Chrome Version **42.0.2311.90** (64-bit), and it does not work.

On my laptop I have Chrome Version **41.0.2272.118 m** and it **does** work.

On my iPhone I have Chrome Version **40.0.2214.73** and it **does** work.

Comment: What is the value of volume?

Comment: It's not directly related, but we found another Audio API bug in the latest  Chrome version that had not been there earlier. This was in some cleanup code, so we could work around it, but there seems to have been some changes in the related implementations as of late. Can't help on the issue specifically.

Comment: I'm using Version 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit). It says it is up to date.

Comment: The version of Chrome on my iPhone is Version 40.0.2214.73 and it works.

Comment: On my laptop I have Chrome Version 41.0.2272.118 m and it does work.

Answer (score 3):

Its because Float values can of type infinite and non-infinite, so in order to prevent this error, check whether the parsed float value is Infinite or not.

For more details on parseFloat() read here [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

```js
function changeVolume(volume) {

  let volume = parseFloat(params.volume);

  if (isFinite(volume)) {
    gainNode.gain.value = volume;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

"volume" is your DIV element containing the volume knob, not a value.  I think you meant "currVolume".

Comment: You were correct about currVolume. That is what it originally was.

I'm not getting the error now... However,  I'm not getting any sound in Chrome either. It does work in Safari, however.

Comment: It's a CORS access issue. You're trying to use a MediaElementAudioSource with an audio source that you don't have access to.  Chrome Canary will print out a message to the console when this happens.